# Is there a performance hit by breaking out tables into different schemas in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, schema

Is there any kind of performance hit when querying by placing tables in different schemas in SQL Server.

For instance if I had 2 tables, **Table1** and **Table2**, and put **Table1** into the ***test*** schema and **Table2** into the ***history*** schema, and then I tried to link the tables in a query, is this implicity slower than having the 2 tables in the same schema?

Comment: There should be no performance hit at all. The microsoft oslo project is using schemas extensively, and if there were performance problems, I am sure this would not have been the case.

Comment: Oslo?  Was that the project moving active directory into SQL Sever?

Comment: It was the modeling project that ended up as SQL Server Modeling. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oslo_%28Microsoft%29

Comment: There is no difference between querying tables from one schema or multiple schemas in the same database. I use Schemas more for grouping objects together than for anything else. To gain performance by separation, I would go towards filegroups on separate physical drives.

Comment: The only place you might hit a penalty is if you don't schema qualify your queries and force the system to figure out where you're pulling from. It's an extremely minor hit, but it's there. Just write the queries correctly and you won't even have that issue.

Answer (score 4):

No there is no performance hit if the tables are in two different schemas.